# Tracing/Benchmarking Haskell Functions

Tags: debugging, haskell, functional-programming

What are the common ways of tracing Haskell function calls for debugging (or benchmarking) purposes? I am currently using the `Debug.Trace` module but I'm looking for something more deterministic. It preferably shouldn't account for the optimiser since I want to test the raw algorithmic performance.

I'd also love to learn about some of the more "formal" methods such as tracking the calls with a writer monad (but I'd prefer not having to resort to formal proofs since they're a little bit unreliable when it comes to predicting behaviours in GHC). Thanks!

Here's an example of how I'm currently testing my implementations:

```hs
import Debug.Trace ( trace )

heavyComputation :: Int -> Int
heavyComputation x = trace "Called" (x+1)

impl1 :: [Int]
impl1 = trace "Impl1" [heavyComputation i | i <- [0..5]]

impl2 :: [Int]
impl2 = trace "Impl2" (let n = heavyComputation 0
                       in [i+n | i <- [0..5]])
```

It'd be nice to have something like this:

```
INPUT: impl2
OUTPUT: [heavyComputation 0, addition 0 1,addition 1 1,addition 2 1,addition 3 1,addition 4 1,addition 5 1]
```

Comment: There shouldn't be anything particularly nondeterministic about `trace`. Do you have an example that sometimes gives one output and sometimes another (that isn't otherwise nondeterministic itself, i.e. doesn't involve multiple threads)?

Comment: Perhaps "deterministic" is the wrong terminology then. I'm trying to say that it shouldn't easily be affected by optimisation/laziness (unless it's trivially lazy (e.g. `fst (1,heavyComputation 0)`)).

Comment: @DanielWagner I guess i'm just wondering whether there exists some sort of "evaluation trace" tool that is generally nice to use for Haskell and can detect some silly behaviours such as `reverse` is quadratic instead of linear (since reasoning about performance in Haskell isn't exactly a fun process :(

Comment: Laziness affects the asymptotic performance in Haskell, so the behaviour you get from `trace` should usually be exactly what you need for reasoning about performance. You have to be careful if you use `traceShow` though, since that can change the laziness of your program. You might also want to use something like [deepseq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.5.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html) to force the result in the end so you actually get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, `trace` does what you need. The result is affected by laziness, but so is everything in Haskell, since that is how evaluation works. You can get the output you asked for, for example like this:

```hs
import Debug.Trace ( trace )

heavyComputation :: Int -> Int
heavyComputation x = trace ("heavyComputation " ++ show x) (x+1)

plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus x y = trace ("addition " ++ show x ++ " " ++ show y) (x + y)

impl1 :: [Int]
impl1 = trace "Impl1" [heavyComputation i | i <- [0..5]]

impl2 :: [Int]
impl2 = trace "Impl2" (let n = heavyComputation 0
                       in [plus i n | i <- [0..5]])

tryBoth :: IO ()
tryBoth = do
    print $ sum impl1
    print $ sum impl2
```

Which gives the expected output

```
Main> tryBoth
Impl1
heavyComputation 0
heavyComputation 1
heavyComputation 2
heavyComputation 3
heavyComputation 4
heavyComputation 5
21
Impl2
heavyComputation 0
addition 0 1
addition 1 1
addition 2 1
addition 3 1
addition 4 1
addition 5 1
21
```

If you try it again, you just get the answers, since the values of `impl1` and `impl2` are memoized and won't be recomputed.

```
*Main> tryBoth
21
21
```

The `print $ sum` is there to force the result of the computation, but there are other ways to do that as well.

If we just force the spine of the list with `print $ length impl2`, it will enter the function, but won't compute any actual sums, nor the `heavyComputation`

```
*Main> tryBoth
Impl1
6
Impl2
6
```

If we just look at the last element of the list with `print $ last impl2`, it will perform a single addition and perform the `heavyComputation` once.

```
*Main> tryBoth
Impl1
heavyComputation 5
6
Impl2
heavyComputation 0
addition 5 1
6
```

As you can see, the behaviour is completely deterministic and predictable, but it does indeed take a while to get used to reasoning about laziness.

Maybe this post can help as well? https://www.well-typed.com/blog/2017/09/visualize-cbn/ It does cover another way to trace the execution of a program, by gradually transforming the source code of the program in a manner that is more or less equivalent to how the actual program would execute.

---

As a final note, there is also an evaluation trace tool in `ghci`, which can be activated by e.g. `:step impl2`, but it is not as helpful as you might expect.